# Simple Paging in datalist as in GridView - NOT CUSTOM PAGING

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, paging, datalist

How can I do simple paging with `DataList`. I don't want to go for `CustomPaging`.

Is there any simple methods like we do Paging in `GridView`.
I am willing to using `DataPager` comtrol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is probably to use the [PagedDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pageddatasource.aspx)

an example with Repeater is shown here: [Adding Paging Support to the Repeater or DataList with the PagedDataSource Class](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121644/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081804-1.aspx)

```
// Populate the repeater control with the Items DataSet
PagedDataSource objPds = new PagedDataSource();
objPds.DataSource = Items.Tables[0].DefaultView;

// Indicate that the data should be paged
objPds.AllowPaging = true;

// Set the number of items you wish to display per page
objPds.PageSize = 3;

// Set the PagedDataSource's current page
objPds.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage - 1;

repeaterItems.DataSource = objPds;
repeaterItems.DataBind();
```